# Bitwise left shift is turning value of my variable negative

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

so I'm trying to shift these values left to store all this data into a 64 bit value. Unfortunately the numbers turn negative right at the first shift, what's causing this? Isn't it only suppose to store the first 41 bits of mil_t time into x? Also why would the remainder of serial and userid be zero?

```
long int gen_id(){
     printf("Calling gen_id...\n");

    unsigned long int mil_t = 1623638363132;
    unsigned long int serial = 10000;
    unsigned int rowId = 5;
    unsigned int userId = 30000;

    printf("Original mil_t: %ld\n", mil_t);
    unsigned long int x = mil_t << 41;
    printf("GEN_ID | MIL_T shift left 41: %ld\n", x);
    unsigned long int tbusMod = userId % serial;
    printf("GEN_ID | tbusMod = userId mod serial: %ld\n", tbusMod);

    x += tbusMod << (64 - 41 - 13);
    printf("GEN_ID | x1 : %ld\n", x);
    x += (rowId % 1024);
    printf("GEN_ID | x2 : %ld\n", x);

    return x;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Original mil_t: 1623638647191

GEN_ID | MIL_T shift left 41: -4136565053832822784

GEN_ID | tbusMod = userId mod serial: 0 

GEN_ID | x1 : -4136565053832822784

GEN_ID | x2 : -4136565053832822779 

FINAL: -4136565053832822779 

TOTAL BYTES: 68
```

Comment: `%lu` is the conversion specifier for `unsigned long`, you are printing as a signed value...

Comment: When looking at the low-order bits of an integer, it's more standard to just use bitwise AND rather than the remainder operator, i.e. instead of `rowId % 1024`, just do `rowid & 0x3ff`.  In the case of an unsigned operand, the compiler will probably do this anyway as an optimization, but I prefer not to use the remainder operator in the first place.  If the operand is signed, then the compiler may need to do additional work to handle a negative operand when replacing the `%` operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program causes undefined behaviour by using the incorrect format specifier. `%ld` is only for `long int`  (and not `unsigned long int`).

Instead use `%lu` to display `x` and `tbusMod`.

---

30000 divided by 10000 gives quotient 3, remainder 0 .

Comment: I see, I also figured out what's going on. I shouldn't be using long unsigned ints for this, but rather just regular unsigned ints, because I'm shifting the bits of the entire length of the integer. Appreciate it

Comment: Technical violation is correct, but since the size is the same, the result is seeing the signed interpretation instead of unsigned.

Comment: @Preston that comment doesn't make much sense but bear in mind that if you are using a 32-bit unsigned int then it would be undefined behaviour to shift by 41. Shift is only well-defined for fewer bits than the width of the type

Comment: @M.M I see, I'm starting to kind of understand what's going on here. Super new to this

Comment: @Preston maybe things will be slightly clearer if you work in hex (e.g. output with `%lx` , and use a hex constant for `mil_t`)

Comment: You can't store the constant `1623638363132` in a 32-bit `unsigned int` accurately; you'll lose a number of the most significant bits.  You can't use `mil_t << 41` unless `sizeof(mil_t) * CHAR_BIT > 41` (so it needs to be a 64-bit unsigned integer, which means `unsigned long long` on Windows and `unsigned long` on Unix.